# Horizontally scrolling table with fixed first column

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to create a table with a fixed first column so that when the user scrolls horizontally, the first column stays where it is, making it easier to interpret the data in the table. I gave the first column `position: absolute` but the issue with that is the `<td>` elements don't resize when the content takes up multiple lines. How do I fix this? I wouldn't mind a solution using javascript for this.

What I have so far: http://jsfiddle.net/Yw679/778/

Also, would it be possible to make the `<thead>` fixed also so that it doesn't go out of view when the user scrolls down but moves with the rest of the columns when the user scrolls horizontally?

Comment: Have you tried `position: fixed;`?

Comment: Yes, same issue occurs with `position: fixed` (http://jsfiddle.net/Yw679/779/)

Comment: you could do sth like this: http://jsfiddle.net/Yw679/780/

Comment: td and th heights still don't match.

Answer (score 0):

I added a new column with class style-hidden for each td and th and some tricky css like this. I hope this will help:

```
.style-hidden{
    width: 0;
    opacity: 0;
    display: block;
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Yw679/782/)